# How to clear local storage values in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: caching, internet-explorer-8, local-storage

I'm using IE8 and the jstorage library to store data in place of cookies. This is all good until i want to clear the stored values. In chrome this is possible by navigating to the content settings page. However in IE8 it only provides an option to clear cookies which doesn't clear the values I've stored in local storage.

Any ideas how i can clear this data? I don't want to display a "clear cache" button

Comment: doesn't look like this is possible using the browser however it can be done using the jStorage API and calling $.jStorage.flush() - which can of course be called from the console in IE8 or alternatively you can trigger the flush method on the click of a button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with local storage support in IE8. The cache does not remove local storage so instead need to call the following from the developer tools console

$.jStorage.flush()

Answer (score 24):

Try `localStorage.clear()` in Console panel of [IE Developer toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359). It returns an "undefined" but seems to clear local storage.

> It is worth mentioning that this function only clears the localStorage of the domain of the current window, not all localStorage values for the browser.
>
> Example: (IE8 issue) If you're website is loading external content within an iFrame, localStorage.clear() won't clear that domain inside of the iFrame unfortunately.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that this function only clears the localStorage of the domain of the current window, not all localStorage values for the browser.