# How to clear Local storage in internet Explorer v8, v9 through Menu options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, internet-explorer

How to clear Local storage in internet Explorer 8,9 through Menu options

I have saved some content in local storage through code and need clear local storage to test functionality. Unfortunately, I am able to clear local storage in IE 11 version 11.0.96 and above,but not below versions like IE 8 and 9.

Below step followed to clear local storage in IE 11 version 11.0.96 and above and its working fine for me.

- Go to menu Tools -> Internet Options -> General Tab.
- Select Check box 'Delete browsing history on exit' [See attached image].
- Restart Internet Explorer.
- [See attached image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0TKU.png)

Please let me know how to clear local storage for IE older versions (8,9).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clear local storage values in Internet Explorer 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12352524/how-to-clear-local-storage-values-in-internet-explorer-8)

Answer (score 2):

click on **Setting icon -> Internet Options -> In general** **tab** click on delete and checked delete browsing history on exit then **restart** and check again.
[image]

Comment: Hi axit i have followed your steps but not working for me.